# Fourier transform of velocities of individual particles vs coarse-grained velocities

Tags: fluid-dynamics, statistical-mechanics, fourier-transform, turbulence

In fluid dynamics, we are interested in $E(k,t)$ the energy in mode $k$. From the velocity field $v(x, t)$, $E(k, t)$ can be computed by simply taking the Fourier transform of $v(x, t)$, squaring, etc. The fourier transform is:
$$v(k, t) = \int dx v(x, t)e^{ikx} $$

Now, let's say that, I'm taking a step back and start looking at the individual particles forming the fluid. Each particle $i$ has a velocity and a position $v_i$ and $x_i$. I can also define an energy at scale $k$ by doing a Fourier transform of the velocity:
$$v_k(t) = \dfrac{1}{L}\sum_{i = 1}^N v_ie^{ikx_i} $$
then squaring, etc...

---

My question is: are the two energies in $k$ space, the one defined from $v(x)$ and the one defined from $v_i$ and $x_i$ related? For example, will we see the turbulent cascade with the particle-dependent definition of $E(k)$. My intuition is that the particle dependent definition, also includes the thermal fluctuations. Thus, the collective motion ($u(x, t)$) might be smeared out by the thermal agitation ($\langle v_i^2 \rangle- \langle v_i \rangle^2$).
The issue being that the fluidy dynamics $v(x, t)$ comes from a coarse graining of $v_i$. Something like an average over neighbors:
$$v(x, t) = \displaystyle{\dfrac{1}{\mathcal N}\sum_{i \textrm{ such that }x_i\in(x\pm dx)}v_i}$$

---

In most articles looking at the structure factor of granular gases for example, the velocity velocity structure factor is computed using $v_i$ and then compared with the prediction of an hydrodynamical theory that uses $v(x)$. Thus, they implicitly assumes that both quantities are the same. For example, this article [Randomly Driven Granular Fluids: large scale structure](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9810251.pdf)
Then, recently, I found an article discussing about the turbulent cascade with molecular dynamics investigations where they define a coarse grained velocity field before taking the fourier transform: [Thermalization in the Lenard-Jones gas](https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.06713). Instead of taking the fourier transform of every individual particles...